# What can I do to thank an answer that I'm not sure is right

Tags: discussion

I asked the following question -- and then attached a bounty when I didn't get any answers:

[Why is JetBlue's IATA code B6?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/19102/why-is-jetblues-iata-code-b6)

There is currently one answer that is well-researched but is still just a hypothesis and thus I don't think that it's properly the "correct" one.

Still, the answerer did do a good deal of research and I want to recognize that.

Is there a way to give the bounty points to this person without making it the "accepted" answer?

Comment: I think redgrittybrick is on the right track. You might wait a day or so and see if sargun dhillun gets an official answer via his method

Comment: I posted an official answer. RedGrittyBrick was right: http://i.imgur.com/qcos5eW.png

Answer (score 3):

You should upvote **all** answers that you think are useful (which is one way to reward them), but only accept the best one, which you should also feel is correct and fully answers the question.

Comment: That. Nails. It.

Answer (score 2):

The bounty system [is independent of the "Accept" system](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/) -- You can award the bounty to any answer you like.

If you do not award the bounty manually than in the absence of an accepted answer half of the bounty amount will automatically be awarded to the highest-voted answer [if it meets certain conditions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).